# Cannot start docker after installation on Windows 10 Home edition

Tags: windows, docker

I am brand new to docker with windows. I have installed the Docker toolbox version as my laptop cannot run hyper-v. After the installation of Docker Toolbox (OS is Windows 10 Home) I run Docker Quickstart Terminal and in the console, I see this:

> Running pre-create checks...
>   Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
>   Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...

I have opened my BIOS menu to try to change this but I am not presented with an option to do so as if it's hidden. I've no idea how to get around this and other StackOverflow solutions are not fixing my issue.

My Laptop model is an Acer Aspire E1-531.

Any help on enabling the VT-X/AMD-v would be brilliant thanks

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Anyway that laptop has a six year old Intel Pentium Dual Core B960 processor which doesn't support virtualization: https://ark.intel.com/products/59836/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B960-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz

Comment: Right okay so, in a nutshell, get a new laptop? Should I be able to run a VirtualBox if the processor can't handle virtualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [link](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/) to see your laptop support VT-X/AMD-v. If not then you have no other choice other than changing your laptop to run hypervisors.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, a new laptop is on the cards.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need a new laptop. If the virtualization is disabled, you may enable it while turning on your system.

From: https://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-technology-in-hp-systems

1. Turn ON the System
2. Repeatedly press Esc key at startup.
3. Press the F10 key for BIOS Setup.
4. Press the right arrow key to System Configuration tab, Select Virtualization
5. Technology and then press the Enter key.
6. Select Enabled and press the Enter key.
7. Press the F10 key and select Yes and press the Enter key to save changes and Reboot.

Comment: what about the OS. I have widows 10 home edition. Should this definitely be professional edition?

Comment: Mine is windows 10 home edition as well. I run docker using virtuabox. https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/docker-on-windows10-home-scratch.html